# php-debug does not work in my ATOM

Tags: php, atom-editor

I'm using ATOM as editor for coding PHP and I've just set up xdebug and php-debug following to each instruction. I'm  using MAMP and actually just added in php.ini file necessary info  to use xdebug and confirmed it is available in my phpinfo and finally installed php-debug in ATOM.
However, I cannot use most of command, suach as continue, step over, step in, step out, and stop, actually　X mark is displayed respectively when my cursor hovered as attached.

[image]

How can i resolve it?